# selection dependent forms in html5

Tags: javascript, html

Say for example I have a simple form consisting of 4 radio buttons on the left hand side of the screen. I want a different form to appear on the right hand side, depending on which radio button is selected (eg an address form for an address radio button, an email input area for an email radio button) How do I implement this?

Im presuming this is beyond the scope of html5 and so some extra client-side programming will be needed (eg javascripts). Im not after a solution per-say (although it could be helpful!)- just some information about how this is implemented in modern webpages, and maybe a link to a tidy tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staying at high level, You should put your rh side forms (suppose you give them an id from 'subform1' to 'subformN') one above the others and make them not visible (example CSS given)

```
.rhForm{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then add onclick listener to your radio buttons

```
<input type='radio' onclick="showform('subform1')">
<input type='radio' onclick="showform('subform2')">
<input type='radio' onclick="showform('subform3')">
<input type='radio' onclick="showform('subform4')">
```

Then declare the function in your script tag in head

```
<script>
function showform(id){
  var n=4; // put your actual subforms count here
  for (var co=1; co<=n; co++)
    document.getElementById('subform' + co).style.visibility='hidden';
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility='visible';
}
</script>
```

Comment: excellent! all works as expected! Is this how 'professional' sites would program simple forms to appear or would they do something much more complicated?

Comment: And on a side note, is it acceptable practice to nestle forms with different submit buttons inside them? (for example if each of the radio buttons you listed above were to invoke a different submit button which did something different with the data) Or would they all have a common submit button which would then do extra calcs to determine where the data was coming from and therefore what to do with it?

Comment: ...well it depends on what you mean with 'professional'. To me a well written, easy readable and maintenance script is professional enough. About the submit approach, again there's no written rule other than (again) maintainability. However for more complex ui, you may want to have a look at dedicated toolkits like for example http://www.gwtproject.org

Comment: Glad that my answer helped out. Would you mind voting / marking it? Thanks!